# Calculating available times from an remapped array in php returns single array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the follow logic in my code.  What is doing is calculating time blocks from 15,30,45,60,90. Then combining the arrays.  I then have a foreach that remmaps values from an api call and sets them in a new array.  What I am trying to do is to have the time values from my foreach compared against the $combined_total_times and do a `array_diff_assoc` with the new value times so that it returns only the values that are not in each array time.

```
function hoursRange( $lower = 0, $upper = 86400, $step = 3600, $format = '' ) {
        $times = array();

        if ( empty( $format ) ) {
            $format = 'g:i a';
        }

        foreach ( range( $lower, $upper, $step ) as $increment ) {
            $increment = gmdate( 'H:i', $increment );

            list( $hour, $minutes ) = explode( ':', $increment );

            $date = new DateTime( $hour . ':' . $minutes );

            $times[] = $date->format( $format );
        }

        return $times;
    }

///counts how many 30,45,60,75 min blocks there is from 8-5pm
  $total_15 = hoursRange( 28800, 61200, 60 * 15, 'h:i a' );
  $total_30 = hoursRange( 28800, 61200, 60 * 30, 'h:i a' );
  $total_45 = hoursRange( 28800, 61200, 60 * 45, 'h:i a' );
  $total_60 = hoursRange( 28800, 61200, 60 * 60, 'h:i a' );
  $total_75 = hoursRange( 28800, 61200, 60 * 75, 'h:i a' );
  $total_90 = hoursRange( 28800, 61200, 60 * 90, 'h:i a' );
////
 $combined_total_times = array_merge($total_15,$total_30,$total_45,$total_60,$total_75,$total_90);

foreach ($result as $value)
{
    $strDay = date('D', strtotime($value['AptDate']));
    $strTime = date("h:i a", strtotime($value['AptTime']));
    if(isset($temp[$value['Location']])){
        $oldIndex = $temp[$value['Location']];
        $remappedData[$oldIndex][$strDay. '_date'] = $value['AptDate'];
        $remappedData[$oldIndex][$strDay. '_time'][] = $strTime;
    }
    else{
        $temp[$value['Location']] = ++$intCurrentIndex;
        $remappedData[$intCurrentIndex]['location'] = $value['Location'];
        $remappedData[$intCurrentIndex][$strDay. '_date'] = $value['AptDate'];
        $remappedData[$intCurrentIndex][$strDay. '_time'][] = $strTime;
    }

}
```

This is an example of the remmaped foreach.

```
[{"location":"City 1","Mon_date":"2020-09-21","Mon_time":["08:00 am","08:30 am","10:00 am","11:00 am","11:45 am","01:30 pm","02:30 pm","03:30 pm","04:15 pm","08:00 am","08:30 am","09:00 am","10:15 am","11:30 am","01:00 pm","02:30 pm","03:45 pm","09:15 am","10:30 am","11:15 am","01:00 pm","02:15 pm","04:00 pm","04:45 pm","08:00 am","10:00 am","11:30 am","01:00 pm","02:15 pm","03:15 pm","04:00 pm","08:00 am","09:00 am","09:30 am","10:00 am","11:15 am","01:00 pm","03:15 pm","04:00 pm","08:00 am","09:00 am","09:45 am","11:00 am","01:30 pm","02:00 pm","04:15 am","04:30 am","04:45 am","05:00 am","05:15 am"],"Tue_date":"2020-09-22","Tue_time":["09:00 am","10:15 am","11:00 am","02:00 pm","03:00 pm","04:00 pm","08:00 am","10:00 am","01:00 pm","01:30 pm","02:15 pm","03:30 pm","08:00 am","10:00 am","11:15 am","01:00 pm","02:15 pm","03:30 pm","08:00 am","09:00 am","11:00 am","01:00 pm","02:00 pm","03:15 pm","04:00 pm","08:00 am","09:00 am","09:30 am","11:15 am","01:00 pm","02:00 pm"]}]
```

What I have tried is this to array the difference first and then passing that value down but that sort of puts it in a seperate array each. :

This however breaks the results into a single array (see example of results below).  I am trying to get the diference in once single array.(see expected results)

```
 $strTime = explode(' ',  date("h:i a", strtotime($value['AptTime'])));
        $total_available = array_diff_assoc($strTime,$combined_total_times);
```

example results after trying with my solution:

```
[{"location":"City 1","Mon_date":"2020-09-21","Mon_time":[["08:00","am"],["08:30","am"],["10:00","am"],["11:00","am"],["11:45","am"],["01:30","pm"],["02:30","pm"],["03:30","pm"],["04:15","pm"],["08:00","am"],["08:30","am"],["09:00","am"],["10:15","am"],["11:30","am"],["01:00","pm"],["02:30","pm"],["03:45","pm"],["09:15","am"],["10:30","am"],["11:15","am"],["01:00","pm"],["02:15","pm"],["04:00","pm"],["04:45","pm"],["08:00","am"],["10:00","am"],["11:30","am"],["01:00","pm"],["02:15","pm"],["03:15","pm"],["04:00","pm"],["08:00","am"],["09:00","am"],["09:30","am"],["10:00","am"],["11:15","am"],["01:00","pm"],["03:15","pm"],["04:00","pm"],["08:00","am"],["09:00","am"],["09:45","am"],["11:00","am"],["01:30","pm"],["02:00","pm"],["04:15","am"],["04:30","am"],["04:45","am"],["05:00","am"],["05:15","am"]],"Tue_date":"2020-09-22","Tue_time":[["09:00","am"],["10:15","am"],["11:00","am"],["02:00","pm"],["03:00","pm"],["04:00","pm"],["08:00","am"],["10:00","am"],["01:00","pm"],["01:30","pm"],["02:15","pm"],["03:30","pm"],["08:00","am"],["10:00","am"],["11:15","am"],["01:00","pm"],["02:15","pm"],["03:30","pm"],["08:00","am"],["09:00","am"],["11:00","am"],["01:00","pm"],["02:00","pm"],["03:15","pm"],["04:00","pm"],["08:00","am"],["09:00","am"],["09:30","am"],["11:15","am"],["01:00","pm"],["02:00","pm"]]}]
```

expected results:

```
[{"location":"City 1","Mon_date":"2020-09-21","Mon_time":["08:00","08:30","10:00","11:00","11:45","01:30","02:30","03:30","04:15","08:00","08:30","09:00","10:15","11:30","01:00","02:30","03:45"
```

(etc,etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All blocks(`30,45,60,75,90`) that you're calculating are multiple of `15` only.
So your first array `total_15` contains all blocks that would be available after combining all of these arrays. So just do

```
$total_15 = hoursRange( 28800, 61200, 60 * 15, 'h:i a' );
// If you don't wanna change code after this line, assign it to combined one.
$combined_total_times = $total_15;
```

First set all values of `$total_15` as available and remove one by one if `time` found during looping.

```
foreach ($result as $value)
{
    $strDay = date('D', strtotime($value['AptDate']));
    $strTime = date("h:i a", strtotime($value['AptTime']));
    
    
    
    if(isset($temp[$value['Location']])){
        $oldIndex = $temp[$value['Location']];
        $remappedData[$oldIndex][$strDay. '_date'] = $value['AptDate'];
        $remappedData[$oldIndex][$strDay. '_time'][] = $strTime;
        
        if(isset($remappedData[$oldIndex][$strDay. '_new'])){
            // remove this time from $strDay_new array.
            $pos = array_search($strTime, $remappedData[$oldIndex][$strDay. '_new']);
            unset($remappedData[$oldIndex][$strDay. '_new'][$pos]);
        }
        else{
            // There can be multiple days in a location. If this is first record for a day then set it to $total_15 except $strTime.
            $remappedData[$oldIndex][$strDay. '_new'] = array_diff($total_15, [$strTime]);
        }
        
        // 
    }
    else{
        $temp[$value['Location']] = ++$intCurrentIndex;
        $remappedData[$intCurrentIndex]['location'] = $value['Location'];
        $remappedData[$intCurrentIndex][$strDay. '_date'] = $value['AptDate'];
        $remappedData[$intCurrentIndex][$strDay. '_time'][] = $strTime;
        // Set when new day index found.
        $remappedData[$intCurrentIndex][$strDay. '_new'] = array_diff($total_15, [$strTime]);;
    }
}
```

Comment: What I am trying to do is take all the times that are NOT in the $$combined_total_times and return the differences.  These will be the "NEW" available times.  All the times in the api call are times are are booked.  I need to see whats available based on comparing $combined_total_times with the api call times.  Does that make sense?

Comment: got an error on array_search.  array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array

Comment: does `total_15` is not an array?

Comment: yes it is.  I think is `$remappedData[$oldIndex][$strDay. '_new']` that is not?

Comment: but we assigned `total_15` in the `$remappedData[$intCurrentIndex][$strDay. '_new'] = $total_15;` same. see last line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221824/discussion-between-chewie-and-jitendra-yadav).

Comment: see the results I sent you.  it returns some new but others it returns the error.

Comment: it sort answers it, what is doing now is brining in future dates instead of looping it from current to the next (until the last one)